# JavaScript function arg into JSTL

Tags: javascript, jstl

1. is there a way to move a javascript function-arg into JSTL tag?

   ```
   function loadList(listName) 

    {  <c:forEach var="item" items="${listName}">  ....  }
   ```
2. Why did this code"

   ```
   x = '${item.category}';
   ```

   work all good and suddenly it didn't work , but change to

   ```
   x = "${item.category}";
   ```

   does work ? I did `alert( message )`in page load to check if the page load success.

Comment: Please post the full code. one-liners dont give us much..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to put a javascript variable into a JSTL tag without a "postback" or reload of the page. However, the reverse (i.e., putting a JSTL tag value into a javascript variable) should be possible.

The reason is the separation between server-side (JSTL) and client-side (Javascript) code.

Answer (score 0):

- With 1st question as what I know, you cant. Instead the reverse of it as your example in 2nd question. As what @jordan mentioned.
- In your 2nd question, I'm not sure why, may be you pass a value with `'` or `single qout` on the `list.category`.